# Improvement of Nodejs CPU intensive tasks using webAssembly

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I am just reading a bit, trying to understand new concepts. Hence my question.

If I understand correctly the concept of [webAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Concepts) is to simply load a code base from another language (C++, C...) and run it inside the Javascript run time.

So, If I follow correctly, I could write some intensive calculation (e.g. Image manipulation) using C++. Compile the code for webAssembly and simply use it inside Nodejs?

Is there a code play environment where I could examine the principles in more depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are many things which could be ported to WebAssembly for a performance improvement. Something that is CPU intensive but with minimal interactivity is ideal, and image manipulation could well be a good candidate for using WASM. There's no guarantee of course that it would be worth the development time compared to writing it natively in JS.

Just today I've discovered two online test environments (from the same team):

- https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/
- https://webassembly.studio/

Comment: To add to @curiousdannii great answer, Wasm is promising for **general purpose** CPU operations, but if you can express your problem in a way that the GPU can be used to do the computation, that might be a higher performance solution. See [gpu.js](http://gpu.rocks/) for ideas on how JavaScript could execute on the GPU.